# Curl error (77): Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Tags: centos, ssl-certificate, ca

I mistakenly delete`/etc/pki/tls`  folder to configure `openssl1.1` package. I have a machine **Centos 8**. When I want to install openssl with **yum install openssl** I have following error because of deleting that directory.

[image]

how can I fix it?

Comment: I solved it with first set **sslverify=0**  into `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` 
after, **dnf reinstall ca-certificates**. At the end, 
set **sslverify=1**  into `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to reinstall the ca-certificates first:

```
sudo yum reinstall ca-certificates
```

This should fix your `/etc/pki/tls` folder. After that you should be able to install other packages again.

If you get SSL errors while running the above command, you need to disable SSL verification for yum and try again. This is done by adding `sslverify=false` in `/etc/yum.conf`. Remember to delete this line after reinstalling the ca-certificates.

Comment: Yes it is also useful answer. Thanks